# QMYSQL several attempts, still not creating library files?

Tags: mysql, qt, driver

So I have  read through several guides of how to properly install the QYMYSQL driver in QT, I have even read instructions which contradict other ones....so really annoyed. Anyhow I have got to the stage where in my 
`...src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql` directory I have these  files/headers...
[mysql folder](http://www.flickr.com/photos/73265886@N08/8305252991/in/photostream)

The problem is that the next step in the guide is to simply run 
`migw32-make` and  I should I have 4 files(.dll and .a) ready in my directory??

However I keep on getting a set of errors, which I have no idea on how to fix. Here is what happens when I try the make command:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/4.8.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql'
g++ -mthreads -shared -Wl,--out-implib,c:\Qt\4.8.4\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmys
qld4.a -o ..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysqld4.dll tmp/obj/debug_shared/ma
in.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_mysql.o  -L
"c:\Qt\4.8.4\lib" -L"c:\Qt\4.8.4\lib" tmp\obj\debug_shared\qsqlmysqld_resource_r
es.o C:\MYSQL\lib\libmysql.lib -lQtSqld4 -lQtCored4
Creating library file: c:\Qt\4.8.4\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysqld4.a
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `codec':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:223: undefined reference to `mysql_character_set_name@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `qMakeError':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:234: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:237: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `qMakeStmtError':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:309: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_error@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:312: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_errno@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN19QMYSQLResultPrivate12bindInV
aluesEv':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:358: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_result_metadata@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:362: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:369: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult7cleanupEv':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:432: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:438: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:440: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:437: undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:446: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_close@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:452: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult5fetchEi':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:496: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_data_seek@12'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:498: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:513: undefined reference to `mysql_data_seek@12'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:514: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult9fetchNextEv':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:529: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:544: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult9fetchLastEv':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:565: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_num_rows@4'
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:570: undefined reference to `mysql_num_rows@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult4dataEi':
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:614: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths@4'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o: In function `ZN12QMYSQLResult5resetERK7QString':
```

It keeps repeating in a similar pattern until it ends with:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql/../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.c
pp:1516: undefined reference to `mysql_real_escape_string@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysqld4.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/4.8.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql'
mingw32-make: *** [debug-all] Error 2

C:\Qt\4.8.4\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>
```

I don't know if I have done something wrong or maybe I should re-install and follow a different installation guide, since there are so many. I would really appreciate it if someone could either tell me why its choking or point me to an installation guide that is credible and actually works

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE SOLVED**

I didn't really figure out what the problem was but guess it had something to do with incompatibility...anyway I worked around it by using different mysql installation file which came with another software, Xampp that I had installed quite a while ago.now I can use the QMYSQL plugin with Qt and it work fine !!!